# Игнорирование окон Unity

Tags: unity3d

Иногда, когда я запускаю проект, у меня вылезают уведомления об обновлении каких то компонентов. Это может быть Unity IAP, Vuforia или еще что-нибудь. Проект паузится и не продолжается, пока я не нажму Skip или ОК, или просто не закрою окно. Как сделать так, чтобы юнити не выводило эти окна или просто их игнорировало и продолжило воспроизведение игры?

Comment: Вот такое ты видишь при запуске проекта? [![Вот такая что-ли?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtvWK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtvWK.png)

Comment: @PiT не конкретно такое, вылезают обновления к разным компонентам иногда. Просто проект автоматизирован и иногда включает-выключает редактор. При включении всегда есть шанс что один из компонентов получит обновление и выдаст окошко, которое подвесит загрузку, пока не нажмешь кнопку *отмена*. Хотелось бы, чтобы можно было бы отключить появление этих окошек

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в unity предусмотрен запуск из командной строки с аргументом

> -batchmode